# What model to fit to a time series data with abnormal fluctuation?

Tags: time-series, stationarity

The plot of the time series data I have:[image]

I can not understand how should I model this kind of dataset.

Try: To estimate the deterministic part of the time series, I have fitted a cubic spline. Then to check for seasonality, I have plotted periodogram to the residual after removing the part explained by the cubic spline, though I do not find any significant spikes in the periodogram. But the process is not still stationary. [I have used ADF test and KPSS test in R to check for stationarity].

Another try: I have done the same thing after making a log transformation.

If you suggest a new model to fit the dataset, also kindly provide the way of estimating the parameters associated with your model.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to appropriate pulses & ARIMA structure you might consider a GLS model incorporating deterministic changepoints in error variance. Tsay discusses that here http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A3382+error+variance for discussions.